# Replace String list with object list - mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo object that currently has a list of Strings in it, see below.

```
{
    "_id" : "One-123-1439251200000",
    "string_list" : [ 
        "123", 
        "321"
    ],
}
```

I'm having trouble creating a mongo script that will transform this string list into an object list (with one of the properties in that object list being each string). See below...

```
{
    "_id" : "One-123-1439251200000",
    "detailed_string_list" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "123",
        "label" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "321",
        "label" : ""
    }, 
}
```

Can anyone help me create this little script? I have tried to look at the [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/) but it's not doing what I am looking for (probably doing something wrong. Thanks so much.

EDIT. I am iterating over a bunch of records and I was experimenting with

```
.forEach(function(doc) {
```

the _id field is the unique Id that I do not need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an "update" operation then using ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations will help you greatly:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.find({ "string_list": { "$exists": true } } ).forEach(function(doc) { 
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ "$unset": { "string_list": "" } });

    doc.string_list.forEach(function(list) {
        bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
            "$push": { 
                "detailed_string_list": { 
                    "_id": list,
                    "label": ""
                }
            }
        });
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 200 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        var bulk - db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
]);

if ( count % 200 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

As a general "transform", then you can use [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) but it is not possible to inject fields like "_id" with a generated value within that process, but you can just use a current value or constant. However you are best off doing this in client code, such as ( javascript and shell ) as that that will generally be more efficient anyway:

```js
   var results = \\ general .find() cursor result
   var counter = 0;

   results = results.map(function(result){ 
       result.detailed_string_list = results.string_list.map(function(list) {
           return { "_id": list, "label": "" };
       });
       delete result.string_list;
       return result;
   });
```

---

But of course if your MongoDB version is less than 2.6 then you cannot use Bulk operations, and just need to use basic updates in a loop instead:

```js
db.collection.find({ "string_list": { "$exists": true } } ).forEach(function(doc) { 
    db.collection.update({ "_id": doc._id },{ "$unset": { "string_list": "" } });

    doc.string_list.forEach(function(list) {
        db.collection.update(
            { "_id": doc._id },
            {
                "$push": { 
                    "detailed_string_list": { 
                        "_id": list,
                        "label": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
]);
```

Comment: I think the 1st example is what I am looking for but there seems to be some syntax issues. ]); should be }); correct? Even when I change that it says that "initializeOrderedBulkOp is not a function" and "bulk has no properties"

Comment: @Zack My bad. Forgot we already worked out you are using a MongoDB less than 2.6. Added example list, but the other still should be usefult to others on more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[$literal](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/)** in aggregation as below :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$string_list"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "detailed_string_list": {
      "$push": {
        "id": "$string_list",
        "label": {
          "$literal": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Or

used  **[$map](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)**

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "detailed_string_list": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$string_list",
        "as": "el",
        "in": {
          "id": "$$el",
          "label": {
            "$literal": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: I'm getting a type error when I use .pretty(). "pretty is not a function (shell):10"  When I take it out, nothing gets updated. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zack It means you aret using MongoDB 2.4 or at least something less than MongoDB 2.6. So just follow the first example without `.pretty()` which is just a "presentation" thing anyway. And replace `$literal` with `$const` in such a case, as it is also an "alias" introduced in MongoDB 2.6, but always existed before as `$const`.

Comment: db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$string_list"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "detailed_string_list": {
      "$push": {
        "id": "$string_list",
        "label": {
          "$const": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

That is not updating anything :/

Comment: @BlakesSeven That does return me a result set, but how do I then apply that result set to all my records?

Comment: @Zack If you actually want to "update" the records then I hav my own answer here.